# How to translate based on origin / world space with homogenous matrix

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, matrix-multiplication

I don't know if this is the right place to ask this or not, since what I'm trying to ask is maybe the basic principle (and its implementation) rather than code specific. I apologize in advance.

Currently, I'm trying to make my own 2D engine using SDL & C++ with my limited knowledge and rusty linear algebra. I'm currently stuck on the transformation part. I've coded my own vectors and matrices class (Vector2, Vector3, Matrix2x2, Matrix3x3). And derived Matrix3x3 into a Transform class to hold the transform of the object in the scene. So, to get the position, it's from these x= elements[0][2], y = elements[1][2], while the angle is from atan(elements[1][0], elements[0][0]).

Now suppose I have this transform for the object:

```
| 0.86602540378         -0.5           50 | 
|      0.5        0.86602540378       -70 | 
|       0                 0             1 |
```

Or position = 50,-70 ; rotation = 30 degree.

Now if I have a translation matrix of:

```
|   1        0        40 | 
|   0        1        20 | 
|   0        0         1 |
```

How do I translate the object not based on the relative space of its rotation but based on the world / global space? So that the final transform of the object would be like this:

```
| 0.86602540378         -0.5           90 | 
|      0.5        0.86602540378       -50 | 
|       0                 0             1 |
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, try applying left-multiplication.  As you're probably aware, matrix multiplication is not commutative in general.  AB is not the same as BA.  If you multiply with the translation matrix on the left and the object transform on the right, you'll likely get it.

Comment: If that were the case, then the translation matrix would be my object's transform, and my object's transform would be the translation matix, which is not what I want to do. I believe the correct way should be by multiplying the rotation matrix with its inverse (or transpose? I forgot) and then multiplying it with my translation matrix, and multiply it back with the rotation matrix. But for now I settle with the pretty hax way of adding the translation values themselves. :P 

Anyway, I think I will close this question as I've "somewhat" solved it. Unelegantly. :P

Comment: Ok, after trying for a while, you were absolutely correct. Multiplying with the transform on the left has indeed resulted in a global transform. And it is a common way to transform  an object globally. My (lack of) vector and matrix knowledge has failed me in this one. Thanks.